# -weak_framework linker arg not recognized by i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2

Tags: macos, ant, frameworks, weak-linking

I am trying to weak-link to the Security framework in Mac OS X (10.8.2,  Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.1).  It appears that the linker is simply not recognizing the '-weak_framework' tag.

This is the linker error I get -

```
[cc] Starting link
[cc] i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: Security: No such file or directory
```

What I found interesting (and hence the reason I believe the '-weak_framework' tag isn't recognized), is that when I change '-weak_framework' to '-thisisgarbage', I still get the same error.

I am running an Ant build script, so this is what's in there -

```
<linkerarg value="-weak_framework" />
<linkerarg value="Security" />
```

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command line option is actually for `ld` (see [manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/ld.1.html)), not `gcc`.  You can pass `ld` command line options via `gcc` using the `-Wl,` flag; so I would expect your `<linkerarg>` to look like this:

```
<linkerarg value="-Wl,-weak_framework,Security" />
```

But you might have to mess about with the quotes to get that quite right...

Comment: Thank you!  It turned out to be <linkerarg value="-Wl,-weak_framework,Security" />

Comment: @chicagozfinest OK; updated the answer with the correct options.